# SQL Server => How to use "case when" on multiple column to show a formula result based on a condition in the same line

Tags: sql, sql-server, group-by, case

I'm trying to provide an overall result of a formula ([CALCULATION]) and then in two extra columns ([NO_TENURE] & [TENURE]) the same calculation but using "CASE WHEN" to filter the information based on another column called [TENURE], everything in one single line like this:

```
MONTH       TYPE       CALCULATION                             NO_TENURE                               TENURE
----------- ---------- --------------------------------------- --------------------------------------- ---------------------------------------
1           TYPE1      5.33333333333                           5.33333333333                           6.81333333333
```

Right now is being shown this way:

```
MONTH       TYPE       CALCULATION                             NO_TENURE                               TENURE
----------- ---------- --------------------------------------- --------------------------------------- ---------------------------------------
1           TYPE1      5.33333333333                           5.33333333333                           NULL
1           TYPE1      6.81333333333                           NULL                                    6.81333333333
1           TYPE2      5.55555555555                           5.55555555555                           NULL
1           TYPE2      5.95238095238                           NULL                                    5.95238095238
```

This is the code I'm using:

```
IF OBJECT_ID('TEMPDB..#TEST') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #TEST
GO

CREATE TABLE #TEST 
(
    MONTH INT,
    TYPE VARCHAR(10),
    TENURE INT,
    NUMERADOR INT,
    DENOMINADOR INT
)

INSERT INTO #TEST
VALUES  (1, 'TYPE1', 35, 320, 60),
        (1, 'TYPE1', 96, 511, 75),
        (1, 'TYPE2', 23, 400, 72),
        (1, 'TYPE2', 102, 500, 84);

SELECT MONTH
       ,TYPE
       ,(SUM(NUMERADOR)/CONVERT(DECIMAL(10,4) ,SUM(DENOMINADOR))) [CALCULATION]
       ,CASE WHEN TENURE < 90 THEN (SUM(NUMERADOR)/CONVERT(DECIMAL(10,4) ,SUM(DENOMINADOR))) END [NO_TENURE]
       ,CASE WHEN TENURE >= 90 THEN (SUM(NUMERADOR)/CONVERT(DECIMAL(10,4) ,SUM(DENOMINADOR))) END [TENURE]

FROM #TEST
GROUP BY MONTH,
       TYPE,
       TENURE
```

I really appreciate the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have TENURE in your GROUP BY, which means that each different tenure in your source data will get a different row in the output.

If you take TENURE out of there, you'll get the one row you want. The your CASE expression won't work, because it should be INSIDE the aggregate functions...

```
SELECT
   MONTH
  ,TYPE
  ,SUM(                            NUMERADOR    ) / CONVERT(DECIMAL(10,4), SUM(                            DENOMINADOR    )) [CALCULATION]
  ,SUM(CASE WHEN TENURE <  90 THEN NUMERADOR END) / CONVERT(DECIMAL(10,4), SUM(CASE WHEN TENURE <  90 THEN DENOMINADOR END)) [NO_TENURE]
  ,SUM(CASE WHEN TENURE >= 90 THEN NUMERADOR END) / CONVERT(DECIMAL(10,4), SUM(CASE WHEN TENURE >= 90 THEN DENOMINADOR END)) [TENURE]
FROM
  #TEST
GROUP BY
   MONTH,
   TYPE
```

The next question is how to avoid the massive repetition. That's done by using sub-queries, CTEs or applied functions, to define expressions in one scope and use them in a different scope.

```
WITH
  NORMALISED_RESULT AS
(
  SELECT
    MONTH,
    TYPE,
    IS_TENURED,
    SUM(NUMERADOR) / CONVERT(DECIMAL(10,4), SUM(DENOMINADOR)) AS CALCULATION
  FROM
    #TEST
  CROSS APPLY
  (
    SELECT
      CASE WHEN TENURE <  90 THEN 0
           WHEN TENURE >= 90 THEN 1
                             ELSE -1 END AS IS_TENURED
  )
    AS TENURE_CHECK
  GROUP BY
    GROUPING SETS(
      (MONTH, TYPE, IS_TENURED),
      (MONTH, TYPE)
    )
)

-- This next part just pivots the normalised results
-- It can be skipped if three rows of normalised results is acceptable.

SELECT
  MONTH,
  TYPE,
  MAX(CASE WHEN IS_TENURED IS NULL THEN CALCULATION END) AS CALCULATION,
  MAX(CASE WHEN IS_TENURED = 0     THEN CALCULATION END) AS NO_TENURE,
  MAX(CASE WHEN IS_TENURED = 1     THEN CALCULATION END) AS TENURE
FROM
  NORMALISED_RESULT
GROUP BY
  MONTH,
  TYPE
```

The `ELSE -1` is only there incase some rows have a `NULL` for the `TENURE`.

Demo : [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=e8b9387e8ff7bce25562f62e1d1f9f59)

Comment: It's possible to differentiate `NULL` values from the Total row by using `WHEN GROUPING(IS_TENURED) = 1`. Great answer anyway, everyone always forgets about `GROUPING SETS`

Comment: @Charlieface But this query needs to differentiate between the grouping levels in the outer query, which would make `GROUPING()` be in the wrong scope. I could expose the result of `GROUPING()` as another column, but don't see the merit.

Comment: @MatBailie thank you very much! This works perfectly and I learned something. I didn't now about GROUPING SETS. Really appreciate it!